# How can my Java program that uses Oracle Database work on other PCs?

Tags: java, database, oracle, sqlite, jdbc

I am new to **Oracle Database** and database management systems in general. At the moment I am developing a Java program that needs to use Oracle Database (contest requirement) but I am wondering, is my program only going to work on my local machine?
I used **SQLite** before, but that is a **server-less** database management system and it only connects to a **file**. Instead, **JDBC** connects to an URL like this:

```
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mkyong","username","password");
```

So, from what I understand, if I send my program to a friend for example, in order for my program to work, Oracle Database must be already installed and configued on his PC.
With SQLite, I only needed to include a ***.sqlite** file with the program that the program used.

Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: You will have to provide a mechanism to provide the database server's address, either by configuration file or by command line parameter, obviously. All programs using database servers need such a mechanism, so there are thousands of examples available.

Comment: You have to have a database.  So SQLLite architecture puts the entire database in a single file.  What about the executable binary that manages that file?  Like MS Access.  The "database" is a single .mdb file, but you still have to have installed Access (the binary executable that manages the file).  Same for Oracle, only the database is far more complex than a single file. But you still have to install the product, and create the database.  And copying the database to another system is more complex that just copying a few files.  (continued . . .)

Comment: @EdStevens - ... except that for SQLite, [sqlite-jdbc](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) includes the binaries for the SQLite engine along with the JDBC driver so a separate install is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Oracle database is accessible by your friend's computer because
 - it is on the same network
 - there is a VPN involved
 - your database is on the internet
then your friend's computer needs an Oracle JDBC driver (a small jar) but not its own installation of the Oracle DBMS.

Otherwise an installation of Oracle is required. Consider Oracle Database XE that according to the website "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition is an entry-level, small-footprint database based on the Oracle Database 11g Release 2 code base.  It's free to develop, deploy, and distribute; fast to download; and simple to administer." There are Windows 64, Windows 32 and Linux 64 downloads available.

Comment: Thanks everyone for clearing up the thick fog in my head! :D